# WiringNG: How I can use interupt?

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi, gpio, nanopi

I have raspberry pi driver code for Some device.
The driver code is using [wiringPy](http://wiringpi.com/) , and use `wiringPiISR` function for gpio interupt.

I am trying use this driver code in [NanoPi](http://www.nanopi.org/).
The NanoPi use [WiringNG](https://github.com/friendlyarm/WiringNP) instead of wiringPy.
But in WiringNG, gpio interupt function is not implemented.
How I can use interupt in NanoPi?